# Render datatable after click in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I need help figuring out how to produce some output (a datatable showing the predicted outcome of a fight), the moment a user clicks on the predict function.

I have tried following a few examples online, but don't seem to be getting my desired action. Not sure I can share much of a reproducible example because the predict button takes the input and runs it through a predictive model I built.

This is the code I have written

```
column(offset=5,width = 8,
           actionButton("gobutton","Predict"),
           dataTableOutput("predictions")),
```

and in the server function

```
observeEvent(input$goButton, {
    output$predictions <- renderDataTable(
      {
        preds3 <- bind_cols(preds,preds2)
        print(cat_model$predict(preds3))
        cat_model$predict(preds3)
      }
    )
  })
```

Currently, nothing happens if I click the predict button in my app

Update:

```
 data <- eventReactive(
    input$goButton, {
        preds3 <- bind_cols(preds,preds2)
        print(cat_model$predict(preds3))
        cat_model$predict(preds3)
    }
  )
  output$predictions <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })
```

but still not getting any output when I click predict
I have also tried wrapping the output on my server in an eventReactive:

This is the output from cat_model$predict(preds3):

```
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 8.77947e-06 0.3193044 0.6806869
```

This is the output I get from dput(cat_model..):

```
structure(c(8.77946992728772e-06, 0.31930435971863, 0.680686860811443
), .Dim = c(1L, 3L))
```

and from glimpse:

```
 num [1, 1:3] 8.78e-06 3.19e-01 6.81e-01
```

Followed the advice given in one of the answers:

```
data <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    preds3 <- bind_cols(preds,preds2)
    print(dput(cat_model$predict_proba(preds3)))
    cat_model$predict_proba(preds3)
  })
  output$predictions <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `eventReactive` is more appropriate here than `observeEvent`. Using your output directly (instead of the calls to `cat$model`), the DT is being rendered correctly here.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            actionButton('goButton', 'Predict'),
            DTOutput('predictions')
        )
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    data <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
        structure(c(8.77946992728772e-06, 0.31930435971863, 0.680686860811443
            ), .Dim = c(1L, 3L))
    })

    output$predictions <- renderDT({
        data()
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, have added the output from preds3

Comment: Paste the output from `dput(cat_model$predict(preds3))` as well as `dplyr::glimpse(cat_model$predict(preds3))`

Comment: Well, using your output, my code renders the correct DT of your output. Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you run my code with my UI -- I wonder if it's a UI issue rather than a server issue? Also what exactly is happening?